# Why doesn't Bernoulli's Principle apply to Current and Resistors in a circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, bernoulli-equation

Bernoulli's principle makes sense when you apply it to fluids. If you decrease the diameter of a pipe then the velocity of the fluid increases because it needs to keep the same rate of fluid moving through the pipe.

So my question is:

If Voltage == Diameter of the pipe

and

Current == Rate of which the fluid is moving

Why do resistors work?
Shouldn't the resistor only actually work within itself but then return the current to it's actual rate once you have passed it?

Or have I taken the analogy of wires being like pipes of water to far?

Comment: Voltage is a driving force, more like the pressure gradient across the pipe than the diameter of the pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've taken the analogy too far: electrons don't actually move through the wire in the way that fluids flow through a pipe. Hence, there is no reason why an analog of Bernoulli's principle should apply.

Answer (score 2):

Well AMR, your analogy is wrong on two levels.   First of all Bernoulli's principal is different from what your example indicates, that you think it is.

And secondly, your  model with Voltage equated to diameter of the pipe is not a good one either.

BUT, all is not lost; comparing water flowing in a pipe with electric current flowing in a circuit, is not a bad analogy; BUT ! here's how you need to adjust your model.

The Voltage in your circuit, would translate to the water pressure being applied to the pipe.

And secondly, your pipe diameter, would relate in some fashion to the resistance in the circuit.

A smaller diameter pipe, would be equivalent to a higher resistance, since that's what would constrict the current or water flow.

So if you think of Voltage or water pressure, as being the driving "force", and pipe diameter, or circuit resistance as being the impediment to flow, then you can see how the water or electric current flow would vary with those variables.

Comment: How do I have Bernoulli's principle incorrect? A decrease in diameter of a pipe would cause low pressure thus increasing velocity.

Comment: ""..Bernoulli's principle makes sense when you apply it to fluids. If you decrease the diameter of a pipe then the velocity of the fluid increases because it needs to keep the same rate of fluid moving through the pipe...""

Comment: I give up; this editor is brain dead, and won't allow ordinary typing edits, so I can't write what I wanted to.  Bernoulli's principle is about the ambient pressure drop in a pipe when the flow speeds up through a restriction.  But for your analogy to work it is the pressure difference along the pipe, that is analogous to the Voltage; not the ambient pressure.    Traffic jams occur because automobile drivers don't obey Bernoulli's principle.  When the road narrows down (fewer lanes) they slow down, instead of speeding up, and the result is a car pileup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the analogy is not perfect as voltage can be thought of only as the pressure gradient across the pipe. This analogy will work quite well. For example, as the voltage increases across a wire, the current flow will increase for a given resistance. Similarly, as the pressure gradient increases across the pipe, the flux or rate of fluid transfer will also increase provided other things are held constant.

Answer (score 0):

So you can apply Bernoulli's theorem but not according to your analogy take velocity of fluid as electric field at that position now electric flux is conserved since no charge enclosed in it so as diameter is large electric field will be less.

Answer (score -1):

True but in my experience traffic is usually jammed up before going through a tunnel but when you get to the other side the traffic magically disappears....same amount of cars same amount of roads space.